# Configuring TLS on JBOSS 6 AS leads to an ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH(In Chrome) or ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap(In Mozilla) error

Tags: java, ssl, browser, https, jboss6.x

I'm trying to configure TLS on production server.

Application Server: JBoss 6.1.0 Final

JDK: 1.6.31

Following is the code from `JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml`:

```
<Connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="${jboss.web.https.port}" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/Keystore.jks"
       keystorePass="dqwssl" server="Server details not present2"
       sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"/>
```

I've kept the `Keystore.jks` file at `JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/`

After the HTTPS configurations, the website is opening on IE8 but not on Chrome and Mozilla.

> Not opening on Chrome(Version:42.0.2311.135),
>   Error-ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
>
> Not opening on Mozilla(Version:37.0.2),
>   Error:ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap

However, it is opening on previous versions on Chrome (before v40) and Mozilla(before v33).

I searched about the issue on various sites and blogs.
What I found is that SSL3 is disabled as it is not safe(POODLE and BEAST attack). All modern browsers are supporting TLSv1.2. But while disabling SSL3, they have also disabled SSL3 cipher suites.

I've tried the cipher configuration in HTTP connector like:

```
<Connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="${jboss.web.https.port}" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/Keystore.jks"
       keystorePass="dqwssl" server="Server details not present2"
       sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" cipher="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"/>
```

I have few questions:

1. While disabling SSL3, does the browsers have also disabled SSL3 cipher suites ?
2. For TLSv1.2: Is JDK1.7 mandatory on server ?
3. What configurations do I need to do to overcome the cipher mismatch issue and the website can open on all modern browsers with TLS?
4. Which ciphers do I need to use ?

Comment: Use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html to test your server configuration to see if TLS 1.x is actually supported and what cipher suites are supported by your server. This and the handshake simulation section may be helpful to determine why the newer versions of Chrome and Firefox fail to connect to your site.

Comment: @AnandBhat : This is not a public domain. It can only be connected on Intranet or VPN. I had tried the above link before, but it was unable to resolve the domain name. Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: I figured the issue. It is with the SSL certificates. When I tried another domain certificate, the application was running on Mozilla, Chrome and IE. I'll share the updated resolution in some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured the issue. The issue occurred because the SSL certificates were not generated properly. The CA certs were not imported in the keystore file. Due to this mistake, the application was not running on Mozilla and Chrome newer versions. But it was working on IE. It was also working on Mozilla and Chrome previous versions. Not able to figure out why. It might be because of newer updates they should have prevented this.